# Array size difference Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is about Python array shape.

What is the difference between array size `(2, )` and `(2, 1)`?

I tried to add those two arrays together. However, I got an error as follows:

> Non-broadcastable output operant with shape (2, ) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2, 2)

Comment: Are you trying to add the values of the arrays or add the array [2] to the array of [2, 2]

Comment: @Shadmoth the OP is almost certainly referring to the shape attribute of `numpy` arrays

Comment: **@yx131**, the 1st one is 1 item tuple and the 2nd one is 2 item tuple. In case of numpy arrays, `(2,)` denotes shape of 1 dimensional array of 2 items and `(2, 2)` denotes the shape of 2 dimensional array (matrix) with 2 rows and 2 colums. If you want to add 2 arrays then either their shape should be same or they should follow the [broadcasting rule](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) of **numpy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the raw memory. But logically, one is a one-dimensional array of two values, the other is a 2D array (where one of the dimensions just happens to be size 1).

The logical distinction is important to `numpy`; when you try to add them, it wants to make a new 2x2 array where the top row is the sum of the `(2, 1)` array's top "row" with each value in the `(2,)` array. If you use `+=` to do that though, you're indicating that you expect to be able to modify the `(2,)` array in place, which is not possible without resizing (which `numpy` won't do). If you change your code from:

```
arr1 += arr2
```

to:

```
arr1 = arr1 + arr2
```

it will happily create a new `(2, 2)` array. Or if the goal was that the 2x1 array should act like a flat 1D array, you can `flatten` it:

```
alreadyflatarray += twodarray.flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

(2,) is an unidimensional array, (2,1) is a matrix with only one column

You can easily see the difference by crating arrays full of zeros using `np.zero` passing the desired shape:

```
>>> np.zeros((2,))
array([0., 0.])

>>> np.zeros((2,1))
array([[0.],
       [0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

**@yx131**, you can have a look at the below code to just have a clear picture about tuples and it's use in defining the shape of numpy arrays.

> **Note**: Do not forget to see the code below as it has explanation of the problems related to **Broadcasting in numpy**.

Also check numpy's broadcasting rule at 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html.

> There's a difference between `(2)` and `(2,)`. The first one is a literal value `2` where as the 2nd one is a tuple.
>
> `(2,)` is 1 item tuple and `(2, 2)` is 2 items tuple. It is clear in the code example.
>
> **Note**: In case of numpy arrays, `(2,)` denotes shape of 1 dimensional array of 2 items and `(2, 2)` denotes the shape of 2 dimensional array (matrix) with 2 rows and 2 colums. If you want to add 2 arrays then their shape should be same.

```
v = (2)   # Assignment of value 2
t = (2,)  # Comma is necessary at the end of item to define 1 item tuple, it is not required in case of list
t2 = (2, 1)  # 2 item tuple
t3 = (3, 4)  # 2 item tuple

print(v, type(v))
print(t, type(t))
print(t2, type(t2))
print(t3, type(t3))

print(t + t2)
print(t2 + t3)

"""
2 <class 'int'>
(2,) <class 'tuple'>
(2, 1) <class 'tuple'>
(3, 4) <class 'tuple'>
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 3, 4)
"""
```

Now, let's have a look at the below code to figure out the error related to broadcasting. It's all related to dimensions.

```
# Python 3.5.2

import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 4]);
arr2 = np.array([7, 6, 3, 8]);
arr3 = np.array([3, 6, 2, 1]);

print(arr1, ':', arr1.shape)
print(arr2, ":", arr2.shape)
print(arr3, ":", arr3.shape)
print ("\n")
"""
[1 4] : (2,)
[7 6 3 8] : (4,)
[3 6 2 1] : (4,)
"""

# Changing shapes (dimensions)
arr1.shape = (2, 1)
arr2.shape = (2, 2)
arr3.shape = (2, 2)

print(arr1, ':', arr1.shape)
print(arr2, ":", arr2.shape)
print(arr3, ":", arr3.shape)
print("\n")
print(arr1 + arr2)
"""
[[1]
 [4]] : (2, 1)
[[7 6]
[3 8]] : (2, 2)
[[3 6]
 [2 1]] : (2, 2)


[[ 8  7]
 [ 7 12]]
"""

arr1.shape = (2, )
print(arr1, arr1.shape)
print(arr1 + arr2)
"""
[1 4] (2,)
[[ 8 10]
 [ 4 12]]
"""

# Code with error(Broadcasting related)
arr2.shape = (4,)
print(arr1+arr2)
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(arr1+arr2)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together 
with shapes (2,) (4,) 
"""
```

So in your case, the problem is related to the mismatched dimensions (acc. to [numpy's broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) ) to be added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array that has shape (2,)

```
In [164]: a = np.array([3,6])
In [165]: a
Out[165]: array([3, 6])        
In [166]: a.shape
Out[166]: (2,)
In [167]: a.reshape(2,1)
Out[167]: 
array([[3],
       [6]])
In [168]: a.reshape(1,2)
Out[168]: array([[3, 6]])
```

The first displays like a simple list `[3,6]`.  The second as a list with 2 nested lists.  The third as a list with one nested list of 2 items.  So there is a consistent relation between shape and list nesting.

```
In [169]: a + a
Out[169]: array([ 6, 12])                # shape (2,)
In [170]: a + a.reshape(1,2)
Out[170]: array([[ 6, 12]])             # shape (1,2)
In [171]: a + a.reshape(2,1)
Out[171]: 
array([[ 6,  9],                        # shape (2,2)
       [ 9, 12]])
```

Dimensions behave as:

(2,) + (2,) => (2,)
   (2,) + (1,2) => (1,2) + (1,2) => (1,2)
   (2,) + (2,1) => (1,2) + (2,1) => (2,2) + (2,2) => (2,2)

That is a lower dimensional array can be expanded to the matching number of dimensions with the addition of leading size 1 dimensions.

And size 1 dimensions can be changed to match the corresponding dimension.

I suspect you got the error when doing a `a += ...` (If so you should have stated that clearly.)

```
In [172]: a += a
In [173]: a += a.reshape(1,2)
....
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,) 
    doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,2)

In [175]: a += a.reshape(2,1)
...
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,) 
    doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,2)
```

With the `a+=...` addition, the result shape is fixed at (2,), the shape of `a`.  But as noted above the two additions generate (1,2) and (2,2) results, which aren't compatible with (2,).

The same reasoning can explain these additions and errors:

```
In [176]: a1 = a.reshape(1,2)
In [177]: a1 += a                
In [178]: a1
Out[178]: array([[12, 24]])
In [179]: a2 = a.reshape(2,1)
In [180]: a2 += a
...
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,1) 
    doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,2)
In [182]: a1 += a2
...
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,2) 
    doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,2)
```